# Get data from within URL

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web-applications

On my website, say test.com, if someone visits test.com/hello I want it to redirect to test.com and pass the string data from after the '/' (in this case "hello") into the page, for example through PHP.

Could I do this with a .htaccess file?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Rewrite Engine

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ processor.php?url=$1
```

Comment: What exactly does that do? I've never really written .htaccess files so I don't really understand them. Thanks!