# Mod Rewrite for unlimited categories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am building a website that will have categories, and I want to access them through the URL.

Example:
http://website.com/category-1/category-2

There is no limit to the number of categories that there could be, so there could be 1 or their could be 1,000.

What would I have to do to make a rewrite that could support many categories? I will then be passing it to php to parse.

Here is what I have tried (Gives 404):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /category.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509965/get-data-from-within-url/16512784#16512784) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would prefer not to have to rely on PHP, the following ruleset may work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$2?catstr[]=$1 [QSA,N] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /category.php?catstr[]=$1&category=1 [QSA,L]
```

A short explanation:

The first rule will match /**directory**/*anything* and redirect to *anything*?catstr[]=**directory**. The QSA flag will force it to preserve query string arguments, and the N flag will force rewrite_rule to rewind the ruleset.

The last rule is just your last one.

So, in order, someone hitting /a/b/c/def will be thrown internally to (those queries will not execute):

/b/c/def?catstr[]=a

/c/def?catstr[]=b&catstr[]=a

/def?catstr[]=c&catstr[]=b&catstr[]=a

/category.php?catstr[]=def&catstr[]=c&catstr[]=b&catstr=a&category=1

It is useful to note that the order will be reversed. This can be used to your advantage and is a feature, not a bug. The exercise on how to put the first rewrite rule to order things in the right way is left as an exercise for the reader.

You can then use every segment of your URI using the `$_GET['catstr']` array in PHP.

Comment: I didn't think of do it as an array! I like that!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, here is what I have.

The .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /category.php?catstr=$1&category=1 [L,QSA]
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
$categories = explode("/", $_GET["catstr"]);
print_r($categories);
```